# node.js dyld: initializer function 0x0 not in mapped image for /usr/local/bin/node Abort trap: 6

Tags: node.js, macos, homebrew, macos-catalina

[image]

I had this issue after a failed attempt to update my node version due to connection lost. Now after the second try, I was able to successfully update my node using `brew upgrade node` command but the issue still persist.

I also noticed that other people had encounter this same problem just a few days ago but it seems they themselves haven't found a solution to it yet.

https://www.cnblogs.com/angfl/archive/2004/01/13/13731315.html

https://blog.csdn.net/alicelmx/article/details/108822531

Any idea on how to fix this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nvm, I found a solution:

1. delete all node versions under **/usr/local/n/versions/node**
2. run `sudo n stable`
3. check node version by running `node -v`